# Global variable in nightwatch. Issue in for loop for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, global-variables, nightwatch.js

I am currently working with node + nightwatch + selenium for automation.
I came across a scenario:

I have defined an array as Global array in nightwatch:

Dev.js

```
'checkforLink':{
    link1:"Some Xpath 1",
    link1:"Some Xpath 2",
    link1:"Some Xpath 3",
    link1:"Some Xpath 4"
},
```

In my custom js  script in custom-commands, I am doing a `for` loop to fetch this links from global variable:

```
exports.command = function(callback) {
  browser = this;

  var data = browser.globals;

  console.log("Before all loop");

  for(var menu_link in data.checkforLink) {
    linkss1 = data.checkforLink.link1; // returns `Some Xpath 1`
    reqvar = data.mainMenuLink.menu_link; // Even though menu_link have value as link1, reqvar is undefined
    browser.click('######') // Click the path
  }

  return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `for(var menu_link in data.checkforLink)`, the variable 'menu_link' will be a string.

To get the property from an object with a string use 'object[string]' syntax. Try `data.mainMenuLink[menu_link];`

This should work as long as data.mainMenuLink.link1 exists.

I noticed in your question all of the properties have the value 'link1'. Hopefully they are different property names in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure your actual problem is related to loop only or you are not able to create a instance using "var data = browser.globals;" so your variable data having {} no value.If this is a case please rename your Dev.js as "globals.js" and provide a path of it as value of a key "globals_path" in "nightwatch.json".