# Data driven test in Nightwatch.js

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

How to create data driven test using Nightwatch.js?
I am using data.js file as global. The content is:

```
module.exports={
    username:'xyz@gmail.com',
    password:'12345',
    urls: {
        login: 'http://www.asdf.com'
    }
};
```

Comment: Mentioned link solution might be helpful for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617463/global-variable-in-nightwatch-issue-in-for-loop-for-node-js/30210672#30210672

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By giving the your file path value in key "globals_path" of  your nightwatch.json file like below, you don't need to rename your js file , you can use data.js file as global file:

```
"globals_path" : "path/to/data.js",
```

and in your test file you can call variable like this :

browser.globals.username etc